# Antivirus constantly detecting temp files as threats

Tags: virus

My antivirus has been constantly detecting threats and It's always temp files. Everyday I open a programme or use/inject a dll and it detects a Gen:Variant.Application.HackTool.180 or Tojan.GenericKD.33997631.

I scanned with Malwarebytes, CCleaner, Tdsskiller, RogueKiller, ESET and others, today. The scans have only detected temp files after they found a backdoor (quite sure that the backdoor is deleted).

I've had this for a while and I haven't found ANYTHING about my current state.

Here are some pictures of my processes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXtxd.jpg

Comment: Unortunately, we are not a malware site.